# Find element in factor ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The problem is this:
1) Prove that $f = x^3+x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Z_5$. 
2) In field K = $\mathbb Z_5/(f)$ $c = x+(f)$. Find in $K$ element $(c^2 + c + 1)^{-1}$ and write it in the form $kc^2+lc+m, k,l,m \in \mathbb Z_5$.

$$$$I know how to prove that $f$ is irreducible. But I don't know how to proceed. $\mathbb Z_5/(f)$ is a ring, so I can work with $c$. How do I find this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you mean $K = \mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]/(f)$. Since $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ is a field, $\mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$ is a Euclidean domain. Note that $f$ is irreducible of degree $3$, so it is relatively prime to any polynomial of lower degree. Hence, there exist polynomials $\alpha(x), \beta(x) \in \mathbb{Z}_{5}[x]$ such that $\alpha(x)(x^{2}+x+1) + \beta(x)f(x)=1$. In the quotient field $K$, reducing both sides modulo $f$ shows that $(\alpha(x) + f(x))(c^{2}+c+1)=1$, i.e. the coset of $\alpha(x)$ in $K$ is the inverse of $c^{2}+c+1$. Use the Euclidean algorithm to compute $\alpha(x)$.

Comment: >In the quotient field K, this shows... 
$$$$Could you expand on that?

Comment: @DarkArchon: I've updated my answer to make things clearer. Please comment if you need further explanation.

Comment: Exactly why $\alpha(x)(c^2+c+1)=1$? Why does the $f(x)$ turn to zero, then we are going in quotient field?

Comment: @DarkArchon: in the quotient field, $f(x)$ is congruent to $0$ modulo the ideal generated by $f(x)$. In other words, since (vacuously) $f(x) \in (f(x))$, the cosets $0 + (f)$ and $f + (f)$ are the same in the quotient field, since $f-0 \in (f)$

Comment: So we just rewrite like this: $\alpha(x)(x^2+x+1)+\beta(x)f(x) = 1 \to alpha(c)(c^2+c+1)+\beta(c)f(c)=1$, $f(c)=0$ and $alpha(c)(c^2+c+1)=1$?

Comment: Essentially, yes. There is some subtlety; these are not functions of $c$, but in the quotient field, $x$ maps to $c$, so your last equation $\alpha(c)(c^{2}+c+1)=1$ is fine. In particular, $\alpha(c)$ is precisely the coset of $\alpha(x)$ in $K$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: By definition of $K,$ we have $c^3+c+1=0,$ and so any polynomial in $c$ can be expressed in terms of powers of $c$ less than or equal to $2.$ Moreover, the elements of $K$ are uniquely expressible as $\Bbb Z_5$-linear combinations of $1,c,c^2.$

Since $f$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z_5,$ then $K$ is a field, and $c^2+c+1$ is non-zero, so has a multiplicative inverse of the form $kc^2+lc+m.$ That is, there exist unique $k,l,m\in\Bbb Z_5$ such that $$1=(c^2+c+1)(kc^2+lc+m)=kc^4+(k+l)c^3+(k+l+m)c^2+(l+m)c+m.$$ Regrouping gives us $$1=(kc+k+l)c^3+(k+l+m)c^2+(l+m)c+m,$$ whence, recalling that $c^3=-c-1,$ we have $$1=-(kc+k+l)(c+1)+(k+l+m)c^2+(l+m)c+m.$$ Can you rewrite the right-hand side as a standard quadratic in $c$ and take it from there?

Comment: I could. Then what? Replace $c$ with $x+(f)$ and consider it done?

Comment: Not at all. Once you've solved for $k,l,$ and $m,$ you can express $(c^2+c+1)^{-1}$ in the desired form.

Comment: Where did $c^4$ went? And why $c^3 = -c-1$?

Comment: The $c^4$ was still there after the regrouping. I simply grouped the terms that had a factor of $c^3$ and pulled out the common factor. Since $c=x+(f),$ then $$c^3+c+1=x^3+x+1+(f)=f+(f)=0+(f).$$ In other words, as far as $K$ is concerned, $c^3+c+1=0,$ and so $c^3=-c-1.$